# which one is better/correct: 'Features' or 'Will be featured'

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

> The upcoming festival *( features / will be featured )* a performance by a
>   famous singer.

Which one is the correct/better one?

Comment: 'will feature', not 'will be featured'

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options here.

1. > The upcoming festival ***features*** a performance by a famous singer.
2. > The upcoming festival ***will feature*** a performance by a famous singer.
3. > A famous singer ***will be featured*** at the upcoming festival.
4. > A performance by a famous singer ***will feature*** at the upcoming festival.
5. > The upcoming festival's ***features include*** a performance by a famous singer.
6. > The upcoming festival ***is going to feature*** a performance by a famous singer.

My preference is for 2. It sounds the most natural without overly complicating things. It's worth pointing out that 1, 2, and 5 put the emphasis on the festival. This makes the most sense if you're talking about the festival and want to discuss interesting attributes of the festival (e.g. "The upcoming festival will feature a performance by a famous singer and tons of great food!"), which seems to be what you're going for.

Comment: for 1st I'll suggest 'The upcoming festival is going to feature a performance by a famous singer.' I'l prefer the second one.

Comment: yw @Pierce Darragh :)